# How do I write this jQuery more efficiently?

Tags: jquery, performance

This is a really basic example, but I'm still a beginner with jQuery and I always struggle with combining jQuery events (functions?).

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('focus', 'input[type=text]', function () {
        this.select();
    });
});
```

I'd like to add in `.on('focus', 'input[type=email]'` and `.on('focus', 'textarea'`, without creating a whole new `.on` function.

Comment: Just separate selectors with commas and that becomes an "OR" condition.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: For multiple events, use a space between them (I realise this seems a little inconsistent) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`multiple selector`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for that,

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('focus click touch', 'input[type=text],input[type=email], textarea', function () {
        this.select();
    });
});
```

Comment: `input[type=text],textarea,input[type=email]`

Comment: Perfect thanks. I had no idea it would be that easy, should have tried that first. What if I wanted to add in on click and on touch too? I tried `$(document).on('focus,click,touch',` but that didn't work

Comment: Great, I'll accept the answer when I'm allowed too.

Comment: @patrickzdb Have a look at the answer now. you should do that by `$(document).on('focus click touch',`

Comment: It seems like `focus` and `click` don't work together. When I tab to focus the text is selected, but if I click it gets selected and then immediately deselects the text and applies the cursor at the end of it.

Comment: and textarea isn't selected, I'll create a codepen and ask a new question